# Set SqlDataSource parameter to null

Tags: asp.net

How do you set a parameter passed to a SqlDataSource to be null?  I have the code below where the parameter "@var1" is set from a TextBox.  However, if that value is not defined I need to set "@var1" to be null so that the [coalesce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) returns true.

Is there a way to do this or am I going about it the wrong way?

I've also tried setting the `DefaultValue="null"` and `dsABC.SelectParameters["@var1"]=null` which both lead to "Input string was not in a correct format" errors.

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsABC" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:abc123 %>" 
   SelectCommand=" SELECT   col1, col2, col3                        
                   FROM table1 as T1
                   WHERE   COALESCE(@var1, T.ID) = T.ID">
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="var1" ControlID="inputA" PropertyName="Value" DefaultValue="0" Type="Int16" />
     </SelectParameters>  
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the **ConvertEmptyStringToNull** and the **CancelSelectOnNullParameter** attributes. The first sets the parameter to null when empty, the second lets the query run (default behavior is to not run a query with a null parameter).

```
       <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="var1" ControlID="inputA" PropertyName="Value" DefaultValue="0" Type="Int16"
 ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" 
CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"  />
         </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip dbugger.  However, by setting this the query never seems to execute.  What I've done in the code behind is set the value of inputA to string.empty.  If I do a trace in Sql Server Profiler the query never runs.  If I set it to an integer it will run correct. Any ideas?

Comment: @s303, forgot one little bit, the CancelSelectOnNullParameter attribute. Edited the answer.

Comment: Good answer, except I believe the CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" needs to go up in the <asp:SqlDataSource> root node.

Comment: FWIW this still didn't work for me until I added `EnableViewState="False"` to the `SqlDataSource` tag (found on MSDN forums if I remember right).